# Find first matching entry and assign the matching entry value to variable

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8

In want to assign the value to variable by using filter and find first (to avoid matching rest and saving iteration).

```
String output = ""

Map<String, Map<String, CustomObj>> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();;

Map<String, CustomObj> isinMap = new HashMap<>();
isinMap.put("REL", new CustomObj("RELIANCE ISIN"));
isinMap.put("AXIS", new CustomObj("AXISBANK ISIN"));

Map<String, CustomObj> cusipMap = new HashMap<>();
cusipMap.put("CREL", new CustomObj("RELIANCE CUSIP"));
cusipMap.put("CAXIS", new CustomObj("AXISBANK CUSIP"));


finalMap.put("ISIN",isinMap);
finalMap.put("CUSIP",cusipMap);


Map<String,String> tradeDetails = new HashMap<>();
tradeDetails.put("ISIN","AXIS");
tradeDetails.put("CUSIP","AXIS2");


finalMap.entrySet().stream().filter(finalMapEntry-> {
String value = tradeDetails.get(finalMapEntry.getKey());
return finalMapEntry.getValue().containsKey(value);

        // I want following
        //output = finalMapEntry.getValue().get(value).get(); //output should be AXISBANK ISIN
    }
).findFirst();
```

I know `findFirst()` will return me first entry in `Optional` but I want the value of inner map key to be assigned to output variable.
IS it possible to do it somehow while streaming and also skipping other iterations if match found on first any nth attempt ?

Comment: `Optional#get()`?

Comment: @donquih0te Optional.get will return me Map<String, Map<String, CustomObj>> so I again have to iterate inner map and match key and get he value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can make use of the `getOrDefault` API effectively here as:

```
String value = tradeDetails.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(trade -> finalMap.getOrDefault(trade.getKey(), Collections.emptyMap())
                .get(trade.getValue()))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst() // find first non null element (existence in Map as key-value)
        .map(CustomObj::getDesc) // as you need the description
        .orElse("");
```

Comment: @I'mNoBody Didn't get you? Duplicate of any other answer? Could you share the link?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
tradeDetails.entrySet().stream()
       .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getValue(),
                                                   finalMap.get(entry.getKey())))
       .map(entry -> entry.getValue().get(entry.getKey()))
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .map(CustomObj::getName)
       .findFirst().orElse("");
```

or

```
finalMap.entrySet().stream() 
         // .filter(entry -> tradeDetails.keySet().contains(entry.getKey()))
            .map(m -> m.getValue().get(tradeDetails.get(m.getKey())))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst()
            .map(CustomObj::getName)
            .orElse("");
```

Comment: two complicated `.map`s :) ...could be simplified [using `getOrDefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722354/1746118)

Comment: @Naman `getOrDefault` handles absent entries. This complicated answer does not even that. It's complicated for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map?

```
Optional<CustomObj> cObjectOpt = finalMap.keySet().stream().filter(k->finalMap.get(k).containsKey(tradeDetails.get(k))).findFirst().map(fk->finalMap.get(fk).get(tradeDetails.get(fk)));
        if(cObjectOpt.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(cObjectOpt.get().get()); 
        }
```